# data's cannot be inserted

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have database contain table named demnads
table contain 11 cell first one is id auto increasement
I want to add data's with this sql command in php :

```
<?php 
$hostname_mystore = "localhost";
$database_mystore = "mystore";
$username_mystore = "root";
$password_mystore = "";
$mystore = mysql_pconnect($hostname_mystore, $username_mystore, $password_mystore) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
mysql_query("set character_set_server='utf8'");
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$sql= "INSERT into demands ( itemname , case , cname , fatora , client , cdate , ctime , prices , cmobile , numbers) values('$item[$i]','$cases[$i]','$customer[$i]','$fatora[$i]','$client[$i]','$dates[$i]','$times[$i]','$price[$i]','$mobile[$i]','$numbers[$i]' )";
?>
```

but data's didn't be inserted

Comment: do echo $sql to print it to the screen and then try execute it on MySQL workbench or phpMyAdmin...

Comment: where is the call to mysql to run the insert statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `mysql_query( $sql, $conn )`

Answer (score 2):

You have switched from the mysql library (which is deprecated) to mysqli:

```
mysqli_connect_errno()
```

You should use one or the other.

Also, embedded array values need to be enclosed in curly brackets`{$item[$i]}`.

This assumes, of course, that these arrays and `$i` are defined elsewhere.

And you haven't shown the statement that actually inserts the data.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your column names with backticks. `case` is a keyword within MySQL and as such can not be used as a column name without the backticks!

```
$sql= "INSERT into demands ( `itemname` , `case` , `cname` , `fatora` , `client` , `cdate` , `ctime` , `prices` , `cmobile` , `numbers`) values('$item[$i]','$cases[$i]','$customer[$i]','$fatora[$i]','$client[$i]','$dates[$i]','$times[$i]','$price[$i]','$mobile[$i]','$numbers[$i]' )";
```

Answer (score 0):

You said your table name is **demnads** . But in Coding you used **demands**? 
Check again.